# passing null in onNext through PublishSubject and filtering that response in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-android

I have a code like this:

```
  getLocationObservable() //this observable returns via PublishSubject the location
          .filter(location -> {
              .....
              Here I want to be able to get a null value for the location
          })
         .flatMap(location -> anotherObservable()
                             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe( new Observer<........
```

In the Location class is it like this :

```
 private PublishSubject<Location> locationPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public Observable<Location> getLocationObservable() {
        return locationPublishSubject;
    }

    and then...
    locationPublishSubject.onNext( foundLocation);
```

now, the `getLocationObservable` is based on a `PublishSubject`, that returns the Location via `onNext`. and then I analyze it inside the `filter` operator. However, sometimes the Location is not found, and it passes null. But passing null in onNext results in a crash. 
More specifically, I get : `UndeliverableException: java.lang.Throwable`
How can that be solved?

Comment: In filter write this: return location != null;

Comment: that doesn't help. The problem is before that : when the PublishSubject send null in onNext, it crashes, without even making it till the `filter`

Comment: Can u add the body of method getLocationObservable() ?

Comment: of course, I edited my post.

Comment: Do you need to receive null in your filter method? Or just ignoring null values by the publishSubject is enough?

Comment: I need to receive null, in order to know I had found a Location or failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rx do not work with `null` eventually throwing an exception.
You can use here a `Wrapper` pattern.

**Example in Kotlin**

```
class Wrapper<T>(val value: T?)
```

Modify your subject to emit location wrapped in the wrapper class. In the filtering option check if it contains `null` or not, like

```
.filter{ it.value != null }
```

**Example in Java**

Add class `Wrapper`

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    public final T value;

    public Wrapper(T value) {
         this.value = value;
    } 
}
```

Then use it when emitting new location and filtering it.

```
public Observable<Location> getLocationObservable() {
        return locationPublishSubject;
}
and then...
locationPublishSubject.onNext(new Wrapper(foundLocation));

.filter(wrapper -> {
    wrapper.value != null;
})
```

Alternatively you can skip emitting location if it is `null`, if it's possible.

Comment: I've edited the post with all my relevant code, could you please help and elaborate more on how to do that in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing something like this:

I assume your foundLocation variable is of type Location which contains 2 properties lat and lng.

In this case you can check your found location if it is null and if so, replace it with an object with lat and lng that has impossible values:

```
if(foundLocation == null) {
   foundLocation  = new Location(-1000, -1000);
}
locationPublishSubject.onNext( foundLocation);
```

And then in your onNext of your code you can check if lat and lng are both equal to -1000:

```
if(foundLocation.getLatitude() == -1000 && foundLocation.getLongitude() == -1000) {
    // here you have a null location
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Optional in `map` method:

```
yourObservable.map(msg -> {
    /// business logic that transforms msg into smth else
    return Optional.ofNullable(transformedMsg);
})
```

And if you don't need those empty Optionals add:

```
.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get);
```